# Access Object Properties in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In my react app, I have an array of objects in a file(users.js) and I have another file(contacts.jsx). I am putting the material ui card in contacts.jsx file and in that card I want to access properties of object.

I have tried to access it by using dot(.) operator but I am getting undefined in console.log. What mistake am I doing and How can I access properties like avatar, email, first_name etc.?

**users.js**

```
const users = [{
    id: 1,
    email: "george.bluth@reqres.in",
    first_name: "George",
    last_name: "Bluth",
    avatar: "https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"
},
    {
        id: 2,
        email: "janet.weaver@reqres.in",
        first_name: "Janet",
        last_name: "Weaver",
        avatar: "https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg"
    }]

    export default users;
```

**contacts.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import FilterListIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FilterList';
import { Button, Card, CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import users from "../constants/users";

const Contacts = () => {
    return (
      <div className="parentDiv">
          {
              console.log(users.email,'email') // Result: undefined 'email'
          }
                <div className="header">
                    <h1>Robo Space</h1>
                    <input className="searchFilter" type='text' placeholder="Search here" />
                    <span className="filterIcon"><FilterListIcon /></span>
                </div>
            <div className="body">
            <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
            <CardMedia
              component="img"
              height="140"
                     img={users.avatar}
              alt="robo img"
            />
            <CardContent>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                {users.first_name}
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
              {users.last_name}
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
              
              <Button size="small">Show More</Button>
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
                </div>
            </div>
  )
}
export default Contacts;
```

Comment: e.g. users[0].email because its an array

Comment: MWO, thank you.

Comment: MWO, Can I do it any other way also? I mean by mapping the users[ ] or some other way.

Comment: sure you can, but what's your expected output?

Comment: simple, I am setting up a card(s) in which I am showing the values from object.

Comment: I want to do something in such a way that I don't have to index it because I can have N no. of objects in an array. So how many indexes will I keep writing for that? I think this approach won't be not recommended.

Comment: I want to have direct access to the key of the object. So do I have to run the map function in contacts.jsx itself?

Comment: yes I posted an answer for that

Answer (score 0):

To access single properties you can use the dot operator like `users[0].email`, to access the properties dynamically you can use `.map()` like that:

```
import React from "react";
import FilterListIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FilterList';
import { Button, Card, CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import users from "./users";

const Contacts = () => {
    return (
      <div className="parentDiv">
          {
              console.log(users[0].email,'email') // Result: undefined 'email'
          }
                <div className="header">
                    <h1>Robo Space</h1>
                    <input className="searchFilter" type='text' placeholder="Search here" />
                    <span className="filterIcon"><FilterListIcon /></span>
                </div>
            <div className="body">
            {users.map((user)=>{
              return (
                <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  height="140"
                  src={user.avatar}
                  alt="robo img"
                />
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                    {user.first_name}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                  {user.last_name}
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions>
                  
                  <Button size="small">Show More</Button>
                </CardActions>
              </Card>
              )
            })}
                </div>
            </div>
  )
}
export default Contacts;
```

Here is a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-platform-e42zx?file=/src/Contacts.js:907-910) in case you need it.

Comment: MWO, thank you again.

Comment: @reactIntern your welcome. so did this answer your question? if not please let me know what im missing. if yes please mark as accepted answer.